# make created variable available in parent environment in r

Tags: r

I am using a function within a function in `R` to create new variables. What I need is to be able to use these variables in the parent environment, BUT not global.

For instance, one solution is to use the global assignment operator `<<-`:

```
f1 <- function(x){

  cat("X is ", x, "\n")
  f2 <- function(){
    cat("X will now be transfromed\n")
    y <<- x + 4 # Use Global assignment
  }

  f2()

  cat("Y is ", y, "\n")
} 
f1(x = 5)
```

But I have over 20 variables, so this will clutter my workspace and is bad practice.

I was wondering if there is a better solution without having to play with concepts such as `vars_to_parent <- new.env()`.

Is there is some elegant `R` sorcery where you have a new assignment operator, maybe something silly such as:

```
`<p-` <- function(){assign variable in such a way that its available in parent}
```

Which could help you to get these newly created variables to parent environment:

```
f1 <- function(x){

  cat("X is ", x, "\n")
  f2 <- function(){
    cat("X will now be transfromed\n")
    y <p- x + 4 # New cool assignment operator
  }

  f2()

  cat("Y is ", y, "\n")
} 
f1(x = 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line of `f` will copy all variables in `f` to the specified environment.  Alternately, replace `as.list(environment())` with `list("a", "b")` or to only copy variables beginning with a lower case letter, say, `as.list(ls(pattern = "^[a-z]"))`

```
if (exists("a")) rm(a)
if (exists("b")) rm(b)

f <- function(envir = parent.frame()) {
  a <- b <- 1
  invisible( list2env(as.list(environment()), envir) )
}
f()
a
## [1] 1
b
## [1] 1
```

Rather than inject the variables directly into the parent another possibility which is a bit cleaner is to return the environment itself:

```
f2 <- function(envir = parent.frame()) {
  a <- b <- 1
  environment()
}
e <- f()
e$a
## [1] 1
e$b
## [1] 1
```

or return a list by replacing the last statement in f2 with:

```
list2env(environment())
```

Comment: This is some beautiful use of environments. I wish this was part of the Advanced R book as an example of nested functions